# Python web socket only sending 1 message

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I've been working on a personal project and would send data from a client to the socket host. For some reason the socket closes once the first message. I've tried searching around of how to solve the issue but couldn't really find anything. BTW I'm really new at sockets and am still trying to learn how to use them.

Host code

```
import socket 
import sys 
from _thread import *

host = '' 
port = 5005 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

try:
    s.bind((host, port)) except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5) print('Waiting for a connection.')

def threaded_client(conn):
    reply = ''
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        reply = reply + data.decode('utf-8')
        print(reply)
        if not data:
            print('someone left')
            break

    conn.close()

while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
```

Client code

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.0.10'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))


l="Connection is Up and Running"

client.send(l.encode())
data = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()

client.send(l.encode())
# print(client.send(l.encode()))
data = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
# print("received data:", data)
client.send(l.encode())
# print(client.send(l.encode()))
data = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
client.close()
```

Output on Host side

```
Waiting for a connection.
connected to: 192.168.0.10:52228
Connection is Up and Running
```

Comment: what happens on the client side?

Comment: so this is what happens: c sends `l`; s recvs and prints `l`; c waits on `recv`; s waits on its `recv`. You need to come up with a protocol or choose from existing ones.

Comment: it is waiting on `data = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()` after sending the first one, and I don't see any code sending anything back from the server side.

Comment: can you further explain what you mean by that i dont really understand, networking in general is pretty new to me

Comment: After calling `client.send(l.encode())` the first time, your client code calls `data = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()` which means it tries to read data. The other end does not send any data (in your server side code), so the client code gets blocked.

Comment: oh thanks that makes a lot more sense, so would having data = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode() be unnecessary or would i need to send something back from the host to the client

Comment: it depends on what you are trying to implement, but I guess you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `client.send(l.encode())` the first time, your client code calls `data = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()` which means it tries to read data. The other end does not send any data (in your server side code), so the client code gets blocked.
                    – khachik